# How to make a hidden gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to keep my grid view hidden until and unless search button is been clicked

```
   <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbkcgry" runat="server" Width="233px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                Auther</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtathr" runat="server" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="143px" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                Book Name</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbknm" runat="server" Width="232px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                Price</td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtprs" runat="server" Width="233px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please guide me with the query.

Comment: Well change it's attribute visible to false and on button click event make it visible .

Answer (score 2):

This one

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" visible="false" ></asp:GridView>
```

---

In button event  make it visible

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             gridview1.visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to make this in server side? It can be easily done at client side code :)

Comment: @Murali What if someone had disabled javascript ?

Comment: @SurajSingh, Who is disabling JavaScript now a days? Inform them like `Your website will not work if you disabled javascript.` Disable javascript in your browser and try use anysites like facebook, gmail, etc :)

Comment: @Murali I don't think your question requires any answers, here you can not define any scope on comments who or where and why should one disable it or not , but just a simple scenario what if ?

Comment: Check my comment for what if. I mentioned `Your website will not work if you disabled javascript.` show it in a message bar

Comment: @SurajSingh, also the ASP.Net framework uses javascript for posting the form to fire events, even including validations. check out viewsource __doPostBack in a page, its a javascript function, which is setting the EventTarget & Args for event driven coding

Comment: @Murali What all this have to do with your recent comment i do not get it , I just replied because you suggested doing this from client side ,I think Nagraj way is more robust .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this very well in client side.

Initially you can set the gridview style to display none in server side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"none");
    //or//gridview1.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
}
```

In a client side when a button is clicked

```
 <asp:Button Text="Search" ID="txtSearch" runat="server"
  OnClientClick="return showGridView()" />
```

In a javascript

```
function showGridView() 
{  
  document.getElementByID("<%=gridView1.ClientID %>").style.display="block";
  return false;
}
```

**Note:**

ASP.Net gridview will be rendered as HTML `<table style="display:none" id="gridView1">`
Please see the viewsource of a page and ensure that it added the display:none

Answer (score 0):

specify a css class to your gridview where you say display: none, then change the css class of gridview to display block, or remove class to gridview